# if else based on output of invoke-webrequest in PS

Tags: powershell

Can someone help me capture only the StatusCode of invoke-webrequest below so that I can determine if a site is up (200) or down (any other code). I think essentially an if else statement will be needed.

NOTE: I don't need the output of invoke-webrequest. This is the code I'm running now with: .\websiteCheck.ps1 https://google.com

```
$url = $args[0]

[Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol = "Tls11"

invoke-webrequest -uri $url -DisableKeepAlive -UseBasicParsing -Method head
```

which returns a lot more info to work with than I need:

```
StatusCode        : 200
StatusDescription : OK
Content           :
RawContent        : HTTP/1.1 200 OK
                X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
                X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
                Cache-Control: private, max-age=0
                Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
                Date: Wed, 20 Feb 2019 05:55:14 GMT
                Expires: ...
Forms             :
Headers           : {[X-XSS-Protection, 1; mode=block], [X-Frame-Options, SAMEORIGIN], [Cache-Control, private,
                max-age=0], [Content-Type, text/html; charset=UTF-8]...}
Images            : {}
InputFields       : {}
Links             : {}
ParsedHtml        :
RawContentLength  : 0
```

I'd just like to do something like:

> if StatusCode = 200 write-host "The site is up"
>   else write-host "The site is down"

This must be based on invoke-webrequest and not something like [Net.HttpWebRequest] $req = [Net.WebRequest]::Create($url) because otherwise it doesn't work properly with url's that do multiple redirects.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are more status codes that can be returned. See [HTTP Status Codes](https://www.restapitutorial.com/httpstatuscodes.html#).

So maybe a bit more fine-grained script would be a better choice?

```
$uri = $args[0]
[Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol = [Net.SecurityProtocolType]::Tls12

try{
    $status = [int](Invoke-WebRequest $uri -UseBasicParsing -DisableKeepAlive -Method Head).StatusCode
    switch ($status) {
        {$_ -ge 100 -and $_ -lt 200}  { Write-Output "The site is up. Statuscode: $status"; break }
        {$_ -ge 200 -and $_ -lt 300}  { Write-Output "The site is up. Statuscode: $status"; break }
        {$_ -ge 300 -and $_ -lt 400}  { Write-Output "The site is redirected. Statuscode: $status"; break }
        {$_ -ge 400 -and $_ -lt 500}  { Write-Output "Client error. Statuscode: $status"; break }
        {$_ -ge 500 -and $_ -lt 600}  { Write-Output "Server error. Statuscode: $status"; break }
        default { Write-Output "The site returned an unhandled status code. Statuscode: $status"}
    }
}
catch {
    Write-Error "An error occurred on Invoke-WebRequest.`r`n$($_.Exception.Message)"
}
```

Instead of the `Invoke-WebRequest` you could also use `[System.Net.WebRequest]`. Something like:

```
$uri = $args[0]
[Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol = [Net.SecurityProtocolType]::Tls12

try{
    # Web request
    $res = ([System.Net.WebRequest]::Create($uri)).GetResponse()
}
catch {
    $res = $_.Exception.Response
}
$status = [int]$res.StatusCode
switch ($status) {
    {$_ -ge 100 -and $_ -lt 200}  { Write-Output "The site is up. Statuscode: $status"; break }
    {$_ -ge 200 -and $_ -lt 300}  { Write-Output "The site is up. Statuscode: $status"; break }
    {$_ -ge 300 -and $_ -lt 400}  { Write-Output "The site is redirected. Statuscode: $status"; break }
    {$_ -ge 400 -and $_ -lt 500}  { Write-Output "Client error. Statuscode: $status"; break }
    {$_ -ge 500 -and $_ -lt 600}  { Write-Output "Server error. Statuscode: $status"; break }
    default { Write-Output "An unhandled error occurred. Statuscode: $status"}
}
# Dispose response if available
if($res){ $res.Dispose() }
```

Comment: Thanks Theo! Works well but I needed to add one more separate Write-Host that would also be displayed with your write-output and I didn't know how to do that. I prefer your script as it's more detailed but I had to go with Kexy's as it was easy for me to add those write-host messages there.

Comment: @yorkman Sure, no worries. It is extremely easy however to add extra `Write-Host` messages before the `break` commands inside the `switch` block.

Comment: Thanks I figured that but where exactly? The switch block has 5 different {$_ -ge's and I want to write-host something for each one. One for the 100 to 200 range, another for 200-300 etc. Do I just add it at the end of each write-output but before the break, and on a new llne? So { write-output "the site is up" then on a new line write-host "1"; break } ?

Comment: Thank you Theo! Out of all the code samples out there yours is the only one that works perfectly regardless of the URL status. I really appreciate your efforts.

Comment: Damn. I spoke too soon. I've come across 2 URL's now that open up fine in IE but the script returns An unhandled error occurred. Statuscode: 0 They're HTTP requests...one of the URL's I got it to work by using my older script which also doesn't work with some sites (while it does with your script). That older script uses Get-WebStatus with net.httpWebRequest.

Comment: Maybe this will help you to help me: If I just run a simple Invoke-Webrequest http://mysite I get The operation has timed out...although I'm using your 2nd code sample which uses System.Net.WebRequest. Strange how IE opens the page fine but invoke-webrequest times out.

Answer (score 0):

Use [<s>property dereferences</s>member access operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_operators#property-dereferences-operator-) and [if](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_if) to do the work.

```bsh
$uri = $args[0]

[Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol = ([Net.SecurityProtocolType]::Tls12, [Net.SecurityProtocolType]::Tls11, [Net.SecurityProtocolType]::Tls, [Net.SecurityProtocolType]::Ssl3)

try {
    if ((Invoke-WebRequest $uri -UseBasicParsing -DisableKeepAlive -Method Head).StatusCode -eq 200) {
        Write-Host "The site is up."
    }
    else {
        Write-Host "The site is down."
    }
}
catch {
    Write-Host "The site is down."
}
```

The script above has been modified, some comments below are obsolete.

Comment: Thanks. The problem with that is it displays errors if the url doesn't resolve like: https://google.com77 instead of "The site is down."

Comment: Also it returns: Invoke-WebRequest : The remote server returned an error: (404) Not Found. if my URL is like https://PrivateURL.com/index?RedirectUrl=%2F While this example is using a bogus URL the page of the real URL does open in a browser.

Comment: @yorkman Updated per your request, it now covers these situations.

Comment: Awesome! Thanks Kexy. Works great but I did have to use this instead: [Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol = "tls12, tls11, tls, ssl3" to support all the various protocols the site may be using.

Comment: @yorkman I thought it was some restrictions around TLS versions :P

Answer (score 0):

This might work

```
$uri = $args[0]

[Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol = [Net.SecurityProtocolType]::Tls12

try{
    if((Invoke-WebRequest $uri -UseBasicParsing -DisableKeepAlive -Method Head).StatusCode -eq 200)
    {
        Write-Output "The site is up."
    }
}
catch {
    Write-Output "The site is down."
}
```