# Get HTTP response code when response code does not equal 200

Tags: powershell, powershell-5.0

Im trying to write a script which loops trough a CSV File with a bunch of links in it. Then i want to check with Invoke-WebRequest if the page is reachable. This works fine if the HTTP response code is "200". But I also want the script to write out the response code when it is somewhat like 4xx, 3xx, 5xx etc. So far the response code variable is just empty.

The problem is that when ''Invoke-WebRequest'' returns not 200(thats kinda the point of the script) it generates an error instead of giving me a clean output with the HTTP Response Code.

My script so far:

```
$Links = Import-Csv -Path 'Path\to\file.csv' -Delimiter ";"

$user = Get-Credential

function Check-Link{
        $name_de = $Link.title_de
        $link_de = $Link.url_de

        Write-Host $link_de
        $HTTP_Response = (Invoke-WebRequest $Link.url_de -Credential $user -Method Head).StatusCode  

        if($HTTP_Response -ne 200){
            Write-Host "The page $name_de is not reachable! Response Code: $HTTP_Response"
        }
        else{
            Write-Host "The page $name_de is reachable!"
        }

}

$DeadLinks

foreach($Link in $Links){
    Check-Link
    Start-Sleep 10
}
```

Now when the Response code does NOT equal 200 the output ist:

```
www.example.com
the page example.com is not reachable! Response Code:
```

The expected output would be:

```
www.example.com
the page example.com is not reachable! Response Code: 401
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [if else based on output of invoke-webrequest in PS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54779910/if-else-based-on-output-of-invoke-webrequest-in-ps)

Comment: I've just it that but the problem still persists. If the response code isn't 200 then the output is simply empty.

Comment: You have to look at the ErrorRecord

Comment: Found the answer: <https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19122378/powershell-web-request-without-throwing-exception-on-4xx-5xx>

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Powershell web request without throwing exception on 4xx/5xx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19122378/powershell-web-request-without-throwing-exception-on-4xx-5xx)