# Output Result Print Success and Failed without Exception error

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

I'm trying to print status code 200/401 in success and failed scenarios.

My script is working with status code 200. but if I want to failed my token, `$StatusCode` in not printing 401.

I need some suggestions for print status code in both scenarios passing one parameters.

`$StatusCode = "Status Code: $([int]$response.BaseResponse.statusCode)`" is working for status code 200 only.

```
if ($response = (Invoke-WebRequest @Params -ErrorAction Stop)) {
    try {
        $Token = (($response.Content) | ConvertFrom-Json).Token
    } catch [System.Net.WebException] {
        $StatusCode = "Status Code: $($_.Exception.Response.StatusCode.Value__) ";
        $Message = " Message: $($_.Exception.Message)"
    }
} 

$StatusCode = "Status Code: $([int]$response.BaseResponse.statusCode)"
```

My `$StatusCode` should works for 200 and 401.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [if else based on output of invoke-webrequest in PS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54779910/if-else-based-on-output-of-invoke-webrequest-in-ps)

Answer (score 1):

For one thing, errors thrown by `Invoke-WebRequest` are never caught in your code. Also, the last line of your code snippet replaces anything that the `catch` block might have assigned to `$StatusCode`. Move both statements into the `try` block. And I'd add another `catch` for handling other exceptions that might occur.

Change this:

```
if ($response = (Invoke-WebRequest @Params -ErrorAction Stop)) {
    try {
        $Token = (($response.Content) | ConvertFrom-Json).Token
    } catch [System.Net.WebException] {
        $StatusCode = "Status Code: $($_.Exception.Response.StatusCode.Value__) ";
        $Message = " Message: $($_.Exception.Message)"
    }
}

$StatusCode = "Status Code: $([int]$response.BaseResponse.statusCode)"
```

into this:

```
try {
    $response = (Invoke-WebRequest @Params -ErrorAction Stop)
    $Token = (($response.Content) | ConvertFrom-Json).Token
    $StatusCode = "Status Code: $([int]$response.BaseResponse.statusCode)"
} catch [System.Net.WebException] {
    $StatusCode = "Status Code: $($_.Exception.Response.StatusCode.Value__) "
    $Message = " Message: $($_.Exception.Message)"
} catch {
    $StatusCode = 0
    $Message = " Message: $($_.Exception.Message)"
    # alternatively re-throw the exception by uncommenting below line
    #throw
}
```

If you want only the status codes 200 and 401 but none of the others you could do something like this:

```
try {
    $response = (Invoke-WebRequest @Params -ErrorAction Stop)
    $Token = (($response.Content) | ConvertFrom-Json).Token
    $StatusCode = "Status Code: $([int]$response.BaseResponse.statusCode)"
} catch [System.Net.WebException] {
    if ($_.Exception.Response.StatusCode.Value__ -eq 401) {
        $StatusCode = "Status Code: $($_.Exception.Response.StatusCode.Value__) "
        $Message = " Message: $($_.Exception.Message)"
    } else {
        throw
    }
} catch {
    throw
}
```